# Al modificar un archivo y guardar cambios, con Django, no se muestran estos cambios en el navegador

Tags: html, python, html5, django, vscode

Al momento de guardar cambios en un archivo `html` dentro de mi entorno de trabajo virtual con `django` y recargar la página en el navegador (el que sea) **no se guarda el último cambio**,  y debo siempre ir a la configuración del navegador y reestablecerlo.

Intenté:

- Deshabilitar el cache.
- Cambiar el puerto del host con `python manage.py runserver 800x` (x número que sea)

Tras hacer esto, el problema sigue, es decir, se mantiene bien por unos minutos y luego vuelve a aparecer.

Comment: Probaste a mantener Mayus pulsada a la vez que das al botón de recargar del navegador? Eso fuerza normalmente a solicitar nueva versión en vez de usar la cacheada.

Comment: Oh enciendo el ordenador y lo reviso inmediatamente

Comment: Muchas gracias te pasaste estoy recien en esto te lo agradezco justo esta semana debo entregar el avance del proyecto si no gg carrera